# Indentify Memory usage in Android App

Tags: android

I have created a Android app.But sometime my app is very slow.

I have checked Android Monitor logs then it displays the below message.

1. WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 121ms
2. I/Choreographer: Skipped 171    frames!  The application may be
   doing too much work on its main    thread.

Could you please help me?

Comment: You should scan the code running in each Activity and background service. Android Monitor wont help you so much to find the issue.

Comment: How can I scan the code?